# Is there a way to programatically pull the sprint number from JIRA from CLI or Groovy?

Tags: groovy, command-line-interface, jira

I want to automate our build so that we usually don't have to fiddle with our versions. Our versions follow the format:

```
${YY}.${Quarter}.${Sprint}.${patch}
```

Seems like I should be able to reach out to JIRA and grab that sprint number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jira has a REST API that also exposes board and sprint info.

Ie. [GET /rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/sprint](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.3.1/?_ga=2.108602178.1947619639.1516019724-235706080.1516019724#agile/1.0/board/%7BboardId%7D/sprint)

You can also add the *state* query parameter to only get the *active* sprint as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.3.1/).

It frequently happens that buildscripts also need info from commit messages or from jira issues for which code changes were made. All of these are accessible through apis like git cli, bitbucket/jira rest api, ...